# jmockit testing fake http response

Tags: jmockit

In my class I have a method `doRequest(HttpRequest, someListener)` that sends a `HttpRequest` and use the listener to handle the returned `HttpResponse`. Based on different `responseCode` 500, 203, etc, the handle method will call different method `A()`,  `B()`. 
Now I want to test whether the listener did what I want it to and verify the `A()`, `B()` methods execute with the correct response code. I am using Jmockit to keep consistency with existing test framework. Is there any way I can mock a fake Http response to this input listener? How can I test this listener's behavior?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: It would be easier to help with your issue if you showed some of your code.

Answer (score 0):

To fake responses **locally** you can use [Jaqen](//www.npmjs.org/package/jaqen), a very light server built for testing scripts that depend of an API.

You set whatever you want it to respond **directly on the request** so it might be just what you are looking for.

**For example:**

```
# Console request to a Jaqen instance listening at localhost:9000
$ curl 'http://localhost:9000/echo.json?foo=bar&data\[name\]=Jaqen&data\[v\]=1.0.0' -i
=> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
=> Content-Type: application/json
...
=> {"foo":"bar","data":{"name":"Jaqen","v":"1.0.0"}}
```

There are several ways to tell it what to do and also **serves static files** to allow loading test pages and assets, check out the [documentation](//github.com/matiasgagliano/jaqen/blob/master/README.md) for more.

It's built on node.js so it's really easy to install and use it locally.

```
# To install it (once you have node.js):
$ npm install -g jaqen

# To run it just type 'jaqen' on the console:
$ jaqen
=> Jaqen v1.0.0 is listening on port 9000.
=> Press Ctl+C to stop the server.
```

That's it!